# When I install a grunt package grunt does not automatically install

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I am very new to Grunt and node so please bear with me. I am on a mac OSX operating system. I will walk you through the scripts I ran in detail to help. In my terminal. First I installed Homebrew using:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then I installed node using homebrew:

```
brew install node
```

Ran the grunt command line interface

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Ran Sass

```
sudo gem install sass
```

Initiated node to update/create my package.json file:

```
npm init


{
  "name": "sass-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Test Project",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js"
  "author": "Jerry Thomas"
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Now here is the strange part

When I ran:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev
```

I got a **UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@>=0.4.0** error

And when I looked into my package.json file. The grunt-contrib-sass pack was installed but grunt wasn't installed.

```
 {
    "name": "sass-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A test to mke sure that Grunt and Sass work",
    "main": "index.html",
    "author": "Jimmy Thomas",
    "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0"
 }
}
```

Isn't npm smart enough to know if you want grunt-contrib-sass you also need grunt, so it installs both of them?

Shouldn't my package.joson file be automatically updated to:
      "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "^0.4.5",
      "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0"
    }

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO. You have to do `npm install grunt --save-dev` and also for your plugins. Check the documentation http://gruntjs.com/getting-started. Pro tip you can do install all your grunt package all together like `npm install grunt grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`

Comment: Ahh, Missed that! Your solution cleared it up. I'll read up about it a bit more